# Should I use nested routes or not?

Tags: api, rest, web-services, routes, architecture

The endpoints I'm planning to use in my document taking app are listed below. I'm currently debating with myself whether I should include `/users/{id}/documents`  or only `/documents`. `/users/{id}/documents` would mean that my routes are very nested and it would be harder to maintain.

So what do you think, does my api design look good, or is there anything you would change?

```
GET /documents
POST /documents/new
PUT /documents/{id}/save
DELETE /documents/{id}/delete
PUT /documents/{id}/share

POST /auth/signup
POST /auth/login
GET /auth/loggedin
POST /auth/logout

PUT /users/{id}/password/update
PUT /users/{id}/email/update
PUT /users/{id}/username/update
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP verbs also have some meaning.

For Example when you use `POST` for `/documents` it means you want to create one. so you don't need the `/documents/new`.
so we can rewrite the routes as bellow:

```
GET /documents
POST /documents
PUT /documents/{id}
DELETE /documents/{id}
PUT /documents/share/{id}

POST /auth/signup
POST /auth/login
GET /auth/loggedin
POST /auth/logout

PUT /users/{id}/password
PUT /users/{id}/email
PUT /users/{id}/username
```

But it's totally up to you have to choose your endpoints.
Some programmers rarely use `PUT` or `DELETE` method.

For example they use `POST` for delete as `/documents/delete/{id}`

I personally like to use all kind of HTTP methods

Comment: I used `/new` to make it clear that it's about creating a new document.

Comment: Yes, that's ok but the `POST` already means you want to create something. look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/)

Comment: What do you think of the design?

Comment: I have already answered your question. the answer is what I think :). also take a look at the post I linked in the comment.